# Compare Dataframe column with numpy ndarray and update value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
Dateframe df:A  B  C  D        E
             1  2  4  6        #Value to be updated for this column  
             12 34 5  54
             4  8  12 4
             3  5  6  2
             5  7  11 27
numpy ndarray(shape(4*1)):
         npar=  ([12]
           [6]
           [2]
           [27]
          )
```

I have above dataframe df and array npar, I want to compare value of column D in array npar. if value of column D is found in array npar anywhere . I want to update column E with 1 else 0 for that row of dataframe df. Kindly suggest how I can do this with sample code.

Comment: `df['E'] = df.D.isin(npar).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), but first is necessery flatten array by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and last convert boolean mask to `integer`s - `True`s are `1`s and `False`s are `0`s:

```
df['E'] = df.D.isin(npar.ravel()).astype(int)
print (df)
    A   B   C   D  E
0   1   2   4   6  1
1  12  34   5  54  0
2   4   8  12   4  0
3   3   5   6   2  1
4   5   7  11  27  1
```

**Detail**:

```
npar = np.array([[12],[6],[2],[27]])
print (npar)
[[12]
 [ 6]
 [ 2]
 [27]]

print (npar.ravel())
[12  6  2 27]

print (df.D.isin(npar.ravel()))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: D, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. npar.ravel() is the key here.